# Running and stopping a processing code automatically

Tags: timer, arduino, processing

What i wanna do is this; I want to run the processing code below, and after 2 minutes it should stop automatically and make itself run again and after 2 min stop again and again. I mean I don't want to run the code by clicking run button manually.

I'm so beginner on processing, I would be so glad if you can answer I desperately need this.

```
import processing.serial.*;

// The serial port:
Serial myPort;
String dataReading = "";
String [] dataOutput = {};

void setup() {
   size(500,500);

   // Open the port you are using at the rate you want:
   myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[7], 9600); 
   //in my case,the Serial port the Arduino is connected to is 9th on the serial list, hence the [8]
   //to get access to the serial list you can use >> println(Serial.list());
   myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw() {
   //...
}

void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
   dataReading = myPort.readString();

   if(dataReading!=null){
      dataOutput = append(dataOutput, dataReading);
      saveData();      
  } 
}

void saveData() {
   println("saving to txt file...");
   saveStrings("data/data.txt", dataOutput); 
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to your code to restart every 2 minutes? I don't see why it would change the behavior.

Comment: Because i want to save the data to text document and i think it saves the datas after the code is stopped. so i wanna do it automatically. And also, actually, i want to replace the values to the new readings. But in this code it appends new ones to the dataOutput array. Do you know how to replace dataOutput with dataReading? Does it work if i change dataOutput to String not array?

Comment: No, the file is written as soon as `saveStrings()` is called. Yes, changing dataOutput to a `String` and replacing `dataOutput = append(dataOutput, dataReading);` with `dataOutput = dataReading;` should do what you want.

Comment: Younwere right about the saving. I dont have to stop the code for saving. However dataOutput=dataReading didnt work because saveStrings in the saveData method accepts only string array i guess :(

Comment: You're right. Try wrapping the string in an array, then: `saveStrings("data/data.txt", new String[]{dataOutput});`

Comment: YES! That works! Thank you sooo much! Appreciates!